# Check which model is the current user an instance of in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

The Employee model in my Django project has a OneToOneField relationship with the built-in Django User model. I have then further inherited this Employee model into two different Manager and Associate models.
Now, when a user logs in, I want to check if this user is a Manager or an Associate in my HTML template so that I can display different options, depending on whether they are a Manager or an Associate. What is the best way to that?

Models.py-

```
GENDER = [('male','Male'),('female','Female')]

class Employee(models.Model):
    user_def = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 10,choices = GENDER)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Manager(Employee):
    dept = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

class Associate(Employee):
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(Manager,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooo, using model inheritance eh? Django has [three types of model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), and based on your problem, it seems like what you need is [Meta inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).

In this case, you want to make your `Employee` abstract and in the `user_def` field, define the `related_name` that provides a backwards relationship from the user to the subclassed models, which in your case would be the `Manager` or `Associate` models. [You can't use any `related_name` however](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name). You need to include the app label and class within the related name, e.g.: `related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s"`. Here, the `app_label` and `class` would be app labels and classes of `Manager` and `Associate` so if you have your models defined in an app called `hr`, then to get the backwards relation from `user` (`user` is the user instance) to manager, you use `user.hr_manager`. Likewise if the user is associate, use `user.hr_associate`.

So, this backwards relation then essentially answers your question because since user has 1-to-1 relation to your `Employee` model, the user can only either be a manager or an associate. They are mutually exclusive. Therefore, if your user is a manager, then that user will return a `Manager` instance if you ask for `user.hr_manager` and None if you ask for `user.hr_associate`.

Now I notice you have allowed `null=True` on your OneToOneField, so it is possible that the user will return None for both instances of `user.hr_manager` and `user.hr_associate`. Therefore, just remember to do a thorough if/elif/else check on the user.

```py
GENDER = [('male','Male'),('female','Female')]

class Employee(models.Model):
    user_def = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices = GENDER
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Manager(Employee):
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Associate(Employee):
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Manager,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

EDIT:
I haven't tested the code, specifically the part about `user.hr_manager`/`user.hr_associate`. They may actually throw an error instead of None if there is no backwards relationship. In this case, you can simply catch and ignore the errors and move on to the next if/elif/else check.

Comment: Good answer except I don't like your naming convention for the related names. Naming a property `is_hr_manager` implies that that property returns either true or false. In this case, it returns the related object. So `hr_manager` would be more appropriate IMO.

Comment: @EduardLuca that's a valid point. I don't know what got into me to name it that way -- probably the context of the question. I'll edit my answer so the name reflects the return value. Thanks for catching it.